# Format issue when Date from Excel to Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, date, selenium-webdriver, format

I am trying to use date from an Excel spreadsheet and pass it to a web table (to a date field) with Selenium WebDriver but the format is messed up.

```
date on excel: 02/23/2019
date on web-table: 90/22/3201
```

or other different weird format.
How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UtilsExcel {

    private Sheet workSheet;
    private Workbook workBook;
    private String path;

    public UtilsExcel(String path, String sheetName) {
        this.path = path;
        try {
            // Open the Excel file
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
            // Access the required test data sheet
            workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(ExcelFile);
            workSheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);

            Assert.assertNotNull("Sheet: "+sheetName+" does not exist",workSheet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getCellData(int rowNum, int colNum) {
        Cell cell;
        try {
            cell = workSheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum);
            String cellData = cell.toString();
            return cellData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

create the class UtilsExcel and save there these 2 methods. first one is constructor which will automatically run and second one is actual method which will bring the date from row and col you want.

after go to your test scenario and call this class and create variable with excel Path, and sheet name on this excel.

```
UtilsExcel utilsExcel = new UtilsExcel(PATH_EXCEL, SHEET_EXCEL);
```

and then you can call and use the second method

```
utilsExcel.getCellData(1,0);
```

then you are just doing sendKeys action with selenium. your `WebElement xpath.sendKeys(utilsExcel.getCellData(1,0));`